Transforming a rectangle into another rectangle using only translations?

This was a question on my math exam competition - I'm totally stumped how to solve it, and for the test next year I want to prepare for questions like these, but I don't even know what type of question this is? Could someone give me insight into how to solve this or just help in general?

Do you see what happens if you move the horizontal line up and down so that the slant line is altered, as a first step?

It's worth noting that the question doesn't state that the edges of the rects are parallel, so a complete proof would need to account for non-aligned rects. ... And FYI, this is a particular instance of the Wallace-Bolyai-Gerwien Theorem: Any two polygons of equal area are "equidecomposable": you can cut up one into a finite number of pieces that rearrange to form another. It happens that there's always a decomposition such that the rearranging requires only translations and half-turns; here, we don't even need the half-turns.

@Blue That's interesting, and I'm sure that's the right approach to the problem, it's just strange because this is for a first-year undergrad math competition, and the theorem seems high level.

@FlinnBella: I'm not suggesting that WBG, or any result of that level, is in play here. I was just mentioning it for interested parties. :) ... As for non-aligned rectangles: It's intuitive that a "slanted" rect can be dissected and translation-ally transformed into a parallelogram with two sides "aligned" with a second rect, and in turn transformed into a "fully-aligned" rect; getting the details in order could be a bit fiddly, and seems to add unnecessary complexity to a timed competition problem. Perhaps the author intended the rects to be aligned, but omitted the explicit condition.

Well. let's se if we can replicate the example.
Let's say we have two rectangle with dimensions Rectangle 1 has dimensions $h\times l$.  And Rectangle 2 has dimesions $\eta \times \lambda$. We are given the areas, $A$, are equal so $A =h\times l$.  We'll assume $h > \eta$. (Thus, obviously $l < \lambda$ as $l =\frac Ah = \frac {\lambda\eta}h$ so $\lambda = l\cdot \frac \eta h$ but $\frac \eta h < 1$)
In rectangle 1 we create triangle $Q_1$ by cutting a line from the upper left corner to a point that is $\eta$ from the top on the right side (remember $\eta < h$ so this is possible).  This is a big right triangle with the vertical leg cut to be $\eta$ and the horizontal leg is the top of rectangle 1 so it is $l$.
In rectangle two we create triangle $P_1$ by cutting a line from the bottom right corner to a point on the top side that is $l$ from the left (remember $l< \lambda$ so this is possible.  This is a big right triangle with the vertical leg that is the right of rectangle 2 so it is $\eta$ and with horizontal let cut to be $l$.  So it has the same leg in same orientation as $Q_1$ so $P_1$ is just a translation of $Q_1$.
Now in rectangle one lets create the other right triangle $Q_2$. Go down from the top left corner and go down the distance of $h -\eta$ and then going perpendicular until it intersects the hypotenuse of $Q_1$.  As it is a right triangle and its top angle is complementary to $Q_1$'s base angle it similar to $Q_2$.
The leg of $Q_1$ that is $\eta$ corresponds to the leg of $Q_2$ that is $h-\eta$ so the leg of $Q_2$ that corresponds to the leg that is $\lambda$ must be $\lambda \times \frac {h-\eta}h= \lambda (1-\frac {\eta}{h})$.   Now $A = \eta\lambda = hl$ so $\frac \eta h = \frac l\lambda$ so that bottom leg of $Q_2$ is $\lambda(1-\frac l\lambda = \lambda - l$.
Okay, lets construct a triangle $P_2$ in rectangle 2. We go from the lower right corner along the bottom to a distance of $\lambda -l$ and then up perpendicularly until it intersects the hypotenuse of $P_1$.  Its base angle is complementary to $P_1$'s bottom angle so $P_2$ is similar to $P_1$ which is congruent to $Q_1$ which is similar to $Q_2$.  So $P_2$ is similar to $Q_2$ and as they both have the same base length of $\lambda-l$ they are congruent and translations of each other.
Let $Q_3$ be the remaining pentagon in Rectangle 1 and $P_3$ be the remaining pentagon in Rectangle 2.  The base of $Q_3$ is base of Rectangle 1 so length $l$.  The left height of $Q_3$ is what remains after we cut the $h-\eta$ leg of $Q_2$ so that is left height of $h- (h-\eta) = \eta$.  The top is were we cut the base of $Q_2$ so it is the length of $Q_2$base of $\lambda - l$. And the right height is what's left after we cut $\eta$ for $Q_1$ from $h$ so it has a right height of $h-\eta$.
So four of the five sides all with right angles in clockwise order are $h-\eta, l, \eta, \lambda - l$.
And $P_3$ is the pentagram left in rectangle 2.  It's length in clockwise order with right angles between are: The height of $P_2$ which was the same as the height of $Q_2$ which was cut to be $h-\eta$; the base of rectangle 2, $\lambda$, minus the base of $P_2$ which was cut to be $\lambda-l$ so $\lambda-(\lambda-l)=l$; the height of rectangle 2 which is $\eta$; and what's left of the top side $\lambda$ have we cut the top side of $P_1$ which was $l$ so $\lambda - l$.
So $P_3$ has the four of the same sides as $Q_3$ and right angles between so they are congruent and orientated the same.
